# GhostScript alternative

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

Im currently using CentOS 5.6 (Ghostscript 8 - ImageMagick-6.2.8 )
and im trying to convert the first image of the pdf to a jpg file.

I understand that my current setup is unable to convert compressed pdf files, but is there an alternative that it can use with the same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'understanding' that Ghostscript is unable to convert 'compressed PDF' is wrong. Where did you pick it up?

PDF by default uses compression internally for most its objects. It's rather unusual to find a PDF 'in the wild' which is completely uncompressed.

Which *exact* version of Ghostscript are you using? (Try `gs -v`).

BTW, you do not need ImageMagick to convert (multipage) PDF to a series of JPEGs. Try this command:

```
 gs \
   -o img_%03d.jpeg \
   -sDEVICE=jpeg \
    input.pdf
```

or, for a resolution of 300 dpi (instead of the default 72 dpi):

```
 gs \
   -o img_%03d.jpeg \
   -sDEVICE=jpeg \
   -r300 \
    input.pdf
```

The `_%03d`-part of the output filename will attach a 3-digit number to the `img`-name that increments with each PDF page.